# Jquery Validation Plugin messages can be written with the html tags itself

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plugin to validate my form.

Now the validation can be only required and/or with digits etc.

The validation messages are written like:

```
 messages: {
            required: "Required.",
            email: "Invalid email",
            url: "Invalid URL."
           }
```

What i notice is that if i write title with HTML tag and dont write the messages: during the validate like:

```
<input id="txtDegreeName" name="txtDegreeName"  title="Please Enter Degree Name"  

 class="required digits" type="text" />
```

Then title becomes Validation message.

but this validation messages will be visible for all validation like

It will show "Please Enter Degree Name" even if digits validation failed.

Problem:

I want to write the all validation messages (required digits url for a single control) inline with HTML tag

Like:

```
   <input id="txtDegreeName" name="txtDegreeName"  title="Please Enter Degree Name" 

   digits="PLease enter digits" class="required digits" type="text" />
```

So the validation plugin shows a different error messages for what what validation failed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plugin has an option to ignore the `title` attribute, which is by default the error message used when no other message has been found:

```
$(...).validate({
    ...
    ignoreTitle: true
    ...
});
```

What you could do is use the [jQuery Metadata](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-metadata) plugin.

It allows you to define the rules/messages within the class attribute in the markup itself like this:

```
<input ... class="{ required:true, email:true, messages: { required:'Please enter your email address', email: 'Please enter a valid email address'}}" />
```

Here is a [demo page](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/custom-messages-metadata-demo.html) for the metadata.

And the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) for the validate plugin options.

Comment: Can you please specify how can i initialize meta or provide a link

Comment: Can i find the which validation is failed for an element i.e like whether it is digits or required etc so that i can use it in errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    if (element.is(":radio"))
                        error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().next());
                    else if (element.is(":checkbox"))
                        error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().next());
                    else {
                        element.parent().next().append(element.attr("digits"));
                        
                    }

Comment: I think the plugin provides the error message directly, not the rule that was broken.

Comment: @ Didier G. I want to know that whether getting error type like "required" or "digits" in the errorPLacement is possible or not. Can you please specify rest else i can do

Comment: You don't get a the broken rule (required, digits...) in errorPlacement, you get the error element (by default a `<label>` with the error message) (**[documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate)**)

Comment: and your solution too isnt working. I use <input id="txtDegreeName" name="txtDegreeName" maxlength="200"  class="{ required:true, email:true, messages: { required:'Please enter your email address', email: 'Please enter a valid email address'}}"     
                        type="text" />

Comment: $(formid).validate(

            {
                meta: "validate",

                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    if (element.is(":radio"))
                        error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().next());
                    else if (element.is(":checkbox"))
                        error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().next());
                    else {
                       // element.parent().next().append(element.attr("digits"));
                        error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
            }
                }}
            );

Comment: Remove `meta: "validate"` from your plugin options **OR** set your metadata like this `class="{ validate: { required:true,...}}"`.